# How to change the height of this background animation?

Tags: html, css, sass, flexbox, css-animations

https://stackblitz.com/edit/reactjs-sample-project-ta1yh3?file=Contact.js

This is a sample. You see how the bubbles stop about 1/3 of the way down the page? How do you extend the animation all the way to the bottom of the screen? I want it to act as a background animation covering the entire background.

In the CSS, the bubbles class is already set to 100vh.

```
.bubbles {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

I also tried setting the body property to 100vh like this but it didn't work:

```
body {
  margin: 0;
  height: 100vh;
}
```

I tried messing around with a bunch of different values and I couldn't get it to work. I did notice that if you turn overflow off the bubbles do start going further down, but not all the way; and it screws up the width and messes up the page entirely so I can't go down that route.

Do any of you more experienced with CSS see where in the CSS I can change the height of the bubbles?

This is the where I got the CSS from:

https://codepen.io/alphardex/pen/jOWMGON

---

For those who don't want to click the StackBlitz, here's the SCSS. Can you tell just from looking at this what property I have to change to change the height? To make it cover the height of the whole screen?

Bubbles.scss

```
body {
  margin: 0;
}

$bubble-count: 25;
$sway-type: "sway-left-to-right", "sway-right-to-left";

@function random_range($min, $max) {
  $rand: random();
  $random_range: $min + floor($rand * (($max - $min) + 1));
  @return $random_range;
}

@function sample($list) {
  @return nth($list, random(length($list)));
}

.bubbles {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.bubble {
  position: absolute;
  left: var(--bubble-left-offset);
  bottom: -75%;
  display: block;
  width: var(--bubble-radius);
  height: var(--bubble-radius);
  border-radius: 50%;
  animation: float-up var(--bubble-float-duration) var(--bubble-float-delay) ease-in infinite;

  &::before {
    position: absolute;
    content: '';
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: hsla(183, 94%, 76%, 0.3);
    border-radius: inherit;
    animation: var(--bubble-sway-type) var(--bubble-sway-duration) var(--bubble-sway-delay) ease-in-out alternate infinite;
  }

  @for $i from 0 through $bubble-count {
    &:nth-child(#{$i}) {
      --bubble-left-offset: #{random_range(0vw, 100vw)};
      --bubble-radius: #{random_range(1vw, 10vw)};
      --bubble-float-duration: #{random_range(6s, 12s)};
      --bubble-sway-duration: #{random_range(4s, 6s)};
      --bubble-float-delay: #{random_range(0s, 4s)};
      --bubble-sway-delay: #{random_range(0s, 4s)};
      --bubble-sway-type: #{sample($sway-type)};
    }
  }
}

@keyframes float-up {
  to {
    transform: translateY(-175vh);
  }
}

@keyframes sway-left-to-right {
  from {
    transform: translateX(-100%);
  }

  to {
    transform: translateX(100%);
  }
}

@keyframes sway-right-to-left {
  from {
    transform: translateX(100%);
  }

  to {
    transform: translateX(-100%);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

for bubbles

you should add

```
.bubbles {
    bottom: 0;
}
```

if you want to go from bottom to top you can make the background having fixed bubbles and remove the height you have given

```
.bubbles {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

Comment: I just tried that, but all it does is start the bubbles from the bottom of the page but the height is the same so the bubbles don't go all the way to the top. Did you try it in the stackblitz sandbox and it worked for you?

Comment: How come even with the height set at "100vh" it doesn't actually cover 100% of the viewport height? What is the "height: 100vh" doing?

Comment: updated for you.. 100vh is not 100%.. it is height of viewport

Answer (score 0):

### change the bubbles class height and bubble animation translateY value

According to this Codepen code, there is an element height and height for the animation. So if you need to animate these bubbles all the way to the bottom or vice-versa you have to change translateY values also.

these are the values you want to change: .bubbles {height:100vh}

```
.bubbles {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh; 
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

animation height (this represents how much height the buddles want to go)

```
@keyframes float-up {
  to {
    transform: translateY(-175vh);
  }
}
```

The starting point of the bubbles: bottom: -75% (bubbles are starting -75 from the 100vh)

```
.bubble {
  position: absolute;
  left: var(--bubble-left-offset);
  bottom: -75%;
  display: block;
  width: var(--bubble-radius);
  height: var(--bubble-radius);
  border-radius: 50%;
  animation: float-up var(--bubble-float-duration) var(--bubble-float-delay) ease-in infinite;
```

So according to your [sample code](https://stackblitz.com/edit/reactjs-sample-project-ta1yh3?file=Contact.js), the simplest answer to your problem is:

change .bubbles {height:200vh} and

change

```
@keyframes float-up {
      to {
        transform: translateY(-375vh);
      }
    }
```

then you can animate bubbles from the bottom all the way to the top but change those values if you want to use it in another place according to page height. you can play with those values.